# How can I make Materialize render in React component?

Tags: django, reactjs, materialize

I am building a simple Django-React application while using Materialize CSS and I have a contact form that I would like for users to pick a date, how do I get the datepicker to show in the Contact component?

I realize that when I navigate to the Contact component, the datepicker does not work whereas if I just import the Contact component into the main App component, the datepicker works perfectly! Please what could be wrong?

It works when I stick the Contact component in the App.js component

````
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Fragment>
                <Header />
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                  <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                </Switch>
                <Contact />
                <Footer />
              </Fragment>
            </BrowserRouter>
```      </Provider>

But the date picker and indeed any plugin for that matter that requires initialization in Materialize css does not work
````

Comment: show the code for Contact component

Comment: Thanks I've found out why it wasn't rendering. I had to use jQuery 2.4 instead of 3.4 and it worked very well!